# Print HTML fragment in a JSP

Tags: jsp

I have two request variables **MyVar** and **MyRequestVar** whose values are set from a Spring MVC controller. **MyRequestVar** is set to some HTML content which uses **MyVar** like this:

```
 <table><tr><td><img src="${MyVar}"></td></tr></table>
```

When I print this variable in JSP like this:

```
${MyRequestVar}
```

it does not substitute the value of **MyVar** in the HTML. How do I print **MyRequestVar** so that value of **MyVar** is substituted in the HTML?

I am using servlet API 2.5 with JSTL 1.2

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

     <!-- Provided Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: How are you exposing it? Are you at the correct servlet spec level to enable JSP EL? There's not enough information here to help.

Comment: Dave Newton, added the servlet API and JSTL version information.

Comment: Unrelated to JSTL since this isn't a tag. What's `MyRequestVar`? How are you exposing either of these values to the view layer?

Comment: MyRequestVar is set to HTML value "<table>... </table>" as mentioned in the question. And MyVar is set to some non-HTML string. Both are set using Spring MVC's ModelAndView#addObject method.

Comment: You can't nest JSP EL like that.